# Android: hide the statusbar in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, statusbar, android-statusbar, chrome-custom-tabs

I launch some url with Chrome Custom Tabs in my app and I want to hide the statusbar from the opened window.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see any options to do this in Custom Tabs docs ([check EXTRA_* options here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html)). Maybe if you hide statusbar before launching Custom Tab it will stay hidden?

Comment: no, I launch the url from activity that hide it's status bar and the Custom Tabs window opened with statusbar.

Comment: following posts in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/xMVERQgRaM4), you may need to use WebView, because Custom Tabs Intent API doesn't provide option to hide statusbar, while WebView is a widget, meaning it's inside yours app window

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's not possible to open a Custom Tab in Chrome with the status bar hidden.

It is possible to enable the bar to hide once the user scrolls down the content by calling [`CustomTabsIntent.enableUrlHiding()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.java#L311)